# Getting and comparing averages from MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to be able to contrast "last weeks" data against "this weeks" data and get the percent change. (i.e. +1.2% or -.5%)

Here's an example of the MySQL table:

Date           | Happy | Sad | Angry | Fearful
2016-04-01 |     2     |   1   |     3    |    0 
2016-04-02 |     3     |   1   |     3    |    1 
2016-04-03 |     0     |   4   |     1    |    2 
2016-04-04 |     1     |   3   |     2    |    1

So pretending that there are at least 14 rows here how would I go about getting the average of the first 7 days, the average of the previous 7 days, and then creating the comparison that shows the percentage difference?

I can get the most recent 7 days averages with the code below, but when I try and repeat it and change the offset it fails:

```
    SELECT AVG(happy), AVG(sad), AVG(angry), AVG(fearful)
      FROM table_name
      LIMIT 0, 7
```

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051057/mysql-date-function-not-working-for-less-than) about less than a date in mysql

Comment: As a note you can create tabular data by indenting four spaces to put it in fixed-width mode. There's no need to use `&nbsp;` to try and line things up.

Comment: And see normalisation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use subqueries to calculate the averages for each week, using date ranges, and join them.

```
SELECT curWeek.happy AS curHappy, curWeek.sad AS curSad, curWeek.angry AS curAngry, curWeek.fearful AS curFearful,
       prevWeek.happy AS prevHappy, prevWeek.sad AS prevSad, prevWeek.angry AS prevAngry, prevWeek.fearful AS prevFearful,
       100*(curWeek.happy - prevWeek.happy)/prevWeek.happy AS happyChange,
       100*(curWeek.sad - prevWeek.sad)/prevWeek.sad AS sadChange,
       100*(curWeek.angry - prevWeek.angry)/prevWeek.angry AS angryChange,
       100*(curWeek.fearful - prevWeek.fearful)/prevWeek.fearful AS fearfulChange
FROM (SELECT AVG(happy) AS happy, AVG(sad) AS sd, AVG(angry) AS angry, AVG(fearful) AS fearful
      FROM tablename
      WHERE date > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AS curWeek
JOIN (SELECT AVG(happy) AS happy, AVG(sad) AS sd, AVG(angry) AS angry, AVG(fearful) AS fearful
      FROM tablename
      WHERE date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK AND NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AS prevWeek
```

Comment: nice solution @Barmar

Comment: ok, wow. So I'm feeling like I overstated my abilities when I deemed myself solidly beginner. How do I use the aliases? Are they just like a variable?

Comment: Yeah, aliases are like variables that refer to tables, subqueries, or columns.

Comment: How would I "echo", lets say current week angry in the body of my page?

Comment: I've updated the query so it returns the current and previous week averages, not just the changes. So you can use `echo $row['curAngry'];`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you everyone!