# how to implement a complicated sql command

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql table in a MySQL with the following records:

```
+------+----------+
| user |   dob    |  
+------+----------+
| john | 1/10/96  | 
| jane | 3/4/97   | 
| jill | 1/8/96   | 
| jack | 2/9/00   |
| jane | 12/14/07 | 
| john | 1/11/98  | 
+------+----------+
```

Here's the command I want to execute:

delete all users with dob < 1/1/00 but keep a user if there exists another user with the same name whose dob >= 1/1/00.

In this example, the johns and jill would be deleted and the janes and jack would stay.

How do I translate the above command into sql?

Comment: It wont delete users where dob >= 1/1/00, you can compile now by using delete command. Try and compile a delete script and we will enhance if needed

Comment: Are you saving dob as String ? MYSQL by default use specific format for dates, so it won't be saved as you wrote in question :
refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051057/mysql-date-function-not-working-for-less-than

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM Users WHERE dob <= '1/1/00'
```

Comment: cant use = , coz it will delete rows with = '1/1/00'. OP doesn't want that  it has to be <

Answer (score 1):

WIth the help of [Delete with Join in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652770/delete-with-join-in-mysql)

I made

```
DELETE FROM table_name a
    INNER JOIN (SELECT count(name) as dupesPostMillenia, name 
                FROM table_name 
                WHERE dob>'1/1/00' 
                GROUP BY name ) b on a.name=b.name
    WHERE a.dob < '1/1/00' and b.dupesPostMillenia=0
```

I think this might help.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE dob < '2000-01-01'
```

Please note : I am considering that you are actually saving date in datetime format in MYSQL. Also, you can use various formats for date in MYSQL. Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14051310/6385845